# 2 события и 1 кнопка. Отписывание от одного и подписка на другое

Tags: c#, события

Всем привет.

Задача: Есть 2 события (А и Б) и 1 кнопка. При выполнении события А (при клике на кнопку) происходит отписка от события А и подписка на событие Б (по аналогии с событием Б).

Сейчас у меня это выглядит так:

```
if(//some condition)
    Button.Click += (sender, e) => Button_Click_A(sender, e, message);
else
    Button.Click += (sender, e) => Button_Click_B(sender, e, message);
```

И в самих же событиях я отписываюсь от них же (извиняюсь за тавтологию):

```
private void Button_Click_A(object sender, EventArgs e, string message)
{
    //some code
    Button.Click -= (sender, e) => Button_Click_A(sender, e, message);
}
```

(2 событие такое же)

И, вроде, всё классно и это работает, но такая реализация мне крайне сильно не нравится. Может есть какой-то более красивый вариант решения этого?

Comment: Правильно не нравится. Отписка же не работает.

Comment: Да, только что протестировал - действительно, не работает. Странно, что сразу этого не заметил. Стоит ли это сделать через 2 делегата, на которые буду клик подписывать. Отписываться после клика от этого делегата?

Comment: А какой смысл в постоянном переопределении обработчика события? Не проще подписать все кнопки на один метод, а уже в самом методе проверять это ваше `if(//some condition)`, выполняя ту или иную логику.

Comment: @Frehzy, можно просто переменную в форме иметь с последнем подписчиком и отписываться через неё.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, подозреваю, там не так всё просто, потому что там где if в вызываемую функцию через замыкание отправляется `message`, который вполне может считаться в подписывающей функции.

Comment: Да, всё именно так. При одном условии отправляется 1 сообщение в ивент. При другом условии - другое сообщение. Я хотел изначально сделать через условие внутри самого ивента, но именно по этой причине не смог придумать, как это лучше реализовать. Решение, которое я сейчас вижу - переподписывать событие клика на разные ивенты

Comment: И как это противоречит с тем, что сказал я? Событие клика по кнопки - это лишь действие, которое происходит по клику, не более. Далее уже вызывайте нужный вам метод в этом событие, с теми же проверками. То есть `if(//some condition) DoSome(message); else DoSome(message2);`, все, вот весь ваш код кнопки, зачем переподписывание на событие, я так и не понял...

Comment: Я хотел так сделать, но что-то внутри меня было против такой реализации. Тем не менее, спасибо. Попробую сделать так, как вы предложили

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно сделать как-то так:

```
private Action<object, EventArgs> currentHandler;

void doSmth()
{
  if (currentHandler != null)
    throw new InvalidOperationException("Attempt to subscribe when already subscribed");

  var message = "Some message";

  if(someCondition)
    Button.Click += currentHandler = (sender, e) => Button_Click_A(sender, e, message);
  else
    Button.Click += currentHandler = (sender, e) => Button_Click_B(sender, e, message);
}

private void Button_Click_A(object sender, EventArgs e, string message)
{
  if (currentHandler != null)
  {
    Button.Click -= currentHandler;
    currentHandler = null;
  }

  MessageBox.Show(message);
}
```

Хотя, в большинстве случаев можно сделать проще:

```
private string handlerMessage;

void doSmth()
{
  handlerMessage = "Some message";
}

private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  MessageBox.Show(handlerMessage);
}
```

Comment: Не ожидал такого развёрнутого ответа. Реализовал примерно так же, как вы написали во 2 варианте. Спасибо, ещё раз)